# Unable to expand single node using cl_salv_tree

Tags: abap, alv

I create an ALV Tree with the class `cl_salv_tree` and want to expand a single node which is the parent to all other nodes and simultaneously the first one to be created.
I use the following code:

```
REPORT.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_kennzahlen,
         beber TYPE t357-beber,
         fing  TYPE t357-fing,
       END OF ty_kennzahlen.
DATA: go_tree       TYPE REF TO cl_salv_tree,
      gr_node       TYPE REF TO cl_salv_node,
      gr_nodes      TYPE REF TO cl_salv_nodes,
      gr_main_key   TYPE lvc_nkey,
      gt_kennzahlen TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_kennzahlen,
      lv_bebertext  TYPE t357.
PARAMETERS dummy.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF go_tree IS NOT BOUND.
    CALL METHOD cl_salv_tree=>factory
      EXPORTING
        r_container = cl_gui_container=>screen0
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_tree = go_tree
      CHANGING
        t_table     = gt_kennzahlen.
    gr_nodes = go_tree->get_nodes(  ).
    gr_node = gr_nodes->add_node(
             related_node   = ''  " Schlüssel zum verwanten Knoten
             relationship   = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child   " Knotenrelationen im Tree
             collapsed_icon = CONV #( icon_closed_folder )
             expanded_icon  = CONV #( icon_open_folder )
             row_style      = if_salv_c_tree_style=>intensified
             text           = CONV #( 'Gesamt'(012) ) ).         " ALV-Control: Zelleninhalt
    gr_main_key = gr_node->get_key( ).
*Children of the parentnode:
    DATA(lt_kennzahlen) = VALUE string_table( ( `Child 1` ) ( `Child 2` ) ).
    LOOP AT lt_kennzahlen INTO DATA(lv_bebertext).
      gr_node = gr_nodes->add_node(
          related_node   = gr_main_key  " Schlüssel zum verwanten Knoten
          relationship   = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child   " Knotenrelationen im Tree
          collapsed_icon = CONV #( icon_closed_folder )
          expanded_icon  = CONV #( icon_open_folder )
          row_style      = if_salv_c_tree_style=>intensified
          text           = CONV #( lv_bebertext ) ).         " ALV-Control: Zelleninhalt
    ENDLOOP.
    gr_nodes = go_tree->get_nodes( ).
    gr_node = gr_nodes->get_node( node_key = gr_main_key ).
    gr_node->expand(  EXPORTING complete_subtree = abap_true  ).
    go_tree->get_tree_settings( )->set_hierarchy_size( 50 ).
    go_tree->display( ).
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: It should work, so I guess the rest of the code is the culprit. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `and want to expand a singular node which is the parent to all other nodes and simultaneously the first one to be created` what should happen first: expansion or creation? show schematically you node hierarchy you wanna to achieve. As far as I know one cannot expand programmatically the dynamically created node in the same loop

Comment: @Suncatcher I create the node first, there I get the gr_main_key and use it afterwards to expand it. I don't create the node in any loop, I only create the children in a loop, which happens way after.

Comment: I had to rewrite your question so that you understand how to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please adjust if needed. I don't reproduce your problem though, all nodes are expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my OOTB snippet based on standard tables:

```
CLASS lcl_tree DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.
  CLASS-DATA:
    go_alv_tree  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_tree,
    gt_empty_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli,
    gt_full_tab  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli.
  CLASS-METHODS:
    create_tree.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_tree IMPLEMENTATION.
METHOD create_tree.
  TRY.
      cl_salv_tree=>factory(
        IMPORTING
          r_salv_tree = go_alv_tree
        CHANGING
          t_table     = gt_empty_tab ).
    CATCH cx_salv_error.
      MESSAGE 'ALV creation error' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDTRY.

  DATA(lo_settings) = go_alv_tree->get_tree_settings( ).
  lo_settings->set_hierarchy_size( 50 ).
  lo_settings->set_hierarchy_icon( CONV salv_de_tree_image( icon_tree ) ).
  DATA(lo_nodes) = go_alv_tree->get_nodes( ).

  SELECT * FROM spfli INTO TABLE gt_full_tab ORDER BY carrid.
  LOOP AT gt_full_tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_line>).
    TRY.
        AT NEW carrid.
          DATA(lo_node) = lo_nodes->add_node( related_node = ''
                                              relationship   = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
                                              data_row       = <fs_line>
                                              row_style      = if_salv_c_tree_style=>emphasized_a
                                              text           = 'Parent node' ).
          DATA(lv_carrid_key) = lo_node->get_key( ).
        ENDAT.
        AT NEW connid.
          lo_node = lo_nodes->add_node( related_node = lv_carrid_key
                                        relationship   = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
                                        data_row       = <fs_line>
                                        row_style      = if_salv_c_tree_style=>emphasized_negative
                                        text           = 'Child node' ).
        ENDAT.
      CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO DATA(exc).
    ENDTRY.
  ENDLOOP.
* !!!this is the stuff the does the things !!!*
  WHILE go_alv_tree->get_nodes( ) IS BOUND.
    lo_node = go_alv_tree->get_nodes( )->get_node( node_key = lv_carrid_key ).
    CHECK lo_node IS BOUND.
    lo_node->expand( ).
    lo_node = lo_nodes->add_node( related_node = lv_carrid_key
                                  relationship   = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
                                  data_row       = <fs_line>
                                  row_style      = if_salv_c_tree_style=>emphasized_c
                                  text           = 'I am the node added on-the-fly' ).
    EXIT.
  ENDWHILE.
ENDMETHOD.                    "create_tree
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_tree IMPLEMENTATION

START-OF-SELECTION.

lcl_tree=>create_tree( ).
lcl_tree=>go_alv_tree->display( ).
```

Pay attention on the `WHILE` block at the end of the method: it does the expanding of the (always last) node by the key saved in the previous loop and adds the additional child node just after expanding.

This is what I was referring to when saying "[you can't just](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/f7e1b703394c6ae70f7b10884555d782.jpg) expand  the node in the same loop". Your `LOOP AT lt_kennzahlen` that creates the nodes cannot be used for expanding them, 'cause the frontend is not updated immediately. That 's why we need separate `WHILE` loop.

Why it is always last? Because we save it in every iteration so it stores the last value always, to get the root node use the `GET_PARENT( )` method.